# Image is showing status=404 after deploying application to Heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I deployed my application to Heroku and once I did that the image isn't appearing. I looked at the Heroku log files and it gives the status=404 for that image. The image appears locally when I run it on my mac book.
The error message is:

```
 2017-12-19T13:42:42.487011+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET 
 path="/images/MyPhoto.jpeg" host=bk-devcamp-portfolio.herokuapp.com 
 request_id=970163c2-4d3a-4b9a-83e0-7204b7cf4f10 fwd="66.194.42.54" 
 dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=1902 protocol=https

 2017-12-19T13:42:42.430206+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET 
 path="/about-me" host=bk-devcamp-portfolio.herokuapp.com 
 request_id=4aebf34c-b6f9-47c3-a678-b779a7efa1ed fwd="66.194.42.54" 
 dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=32ms status=200 bytes=11732 protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

heroku describes how to fix the asset precompiling issue: [Heroku Assets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline)

**Fix 1)**

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

**Fix 2)**
in "config/application.rb" and add this line:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Alternatively you can achieve the same result by including the

`rails_12factor` 
gem in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```